# C#, How to set the cursor position manually

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor, coordinates

I did the "Get Coordinates" part and I need to do the "Set" part, where I can enter the coordinates manually and press "Set" button to make the "Blue Cirlce" to be appeared with the coordinates that I have entered in `textBox2` on `pictureBox1`.
This code for is "Get":

```
    int mouseX, mouseY;
    Pen bluePen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 1);
    private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "X = " + e.X + " ; Y = " + e.Y;
    }
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseX = e.X;
        mouseY = e.Y;
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }
    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle circle = new Rectangle(mouseX - 8, mouseY - 8, 16, 16);
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(bluePen, circle);
    }
```

[image: The form]

Comment: What problems are you having with the set part?

Comment: look into string tryParse and Convert.Toint16.. Or even better [PointConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pointconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the button click event processing method 'ButtonSet_Click' to the 'set' button.

```
    private void ButtonSet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                    
        Point p = getXYfromTextBox();
        Rectangle circle = new Rectangle(p.X - 8, p.Y - 8, 16, 16);
        Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        g.DrawEllipse(redPen, circle);
    }

    //this method can be optimized
    private Point getXYfromTextBox()
    {
        string xy = textBox2.Text.Trim();
        string[] xys = xy.Split(';');
        mouseX = Convert.ToInt32(xys[0].Split('=')[1].Trim());
        mouseY = Convert.ToInt32(xys[1].Split('=')[1].Trim());
        Point p = new Point(mouseX, mouseY);
        return p;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to find a way to parse your input into coordinates. Try this (you need to carefully validate the input string and handle the potential exception thrown when casting string to int).

```
private void btnSet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string input = tbInput.Text.Trim(); 
    string[] parts = input.Split(",".ToCharArray()); //assume your coordinates are commas-separated, like "80,100"
    if (parts.Length == 2)
    {
        mouseX = int.Parse(parts[0]);
        mouseY = int.Parse(parts[1]);
        pictureBox1.Refresh(); //Now force picturebox to repaint
    }
}
```